# How to indicates to ui component when async jobs finishes?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

I have a manager class that communicates with a view component, and this manager class has a method that performing bunch of api calls before it returns a value, so I want the component to have some kind of indicator for when the api calls ended cause I need to disable some button while the data still keep on coming, so did this:

```
export class MyManager {

 public stillBringingData = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);


 public myAsyncFunc(animals: Animal[]): void {

    let counter: number = 0;

    animals.forEach((animal: Animal) => {
      counter++;
      this._myApService.getAnimalInfo(animal.id).subscribe((animalInfo: AnimalInfo) => {
        //currentAnimalInfo is some behaviour subject hat the client listen too
        this.currentAnimalInfo.next(animalInfo)
      });
      this.stillBringingData.next(counter === animals.length)
    });
  }


}
```

and the ui component listening to this behaviour subject with a subscription.

it feels a bit clumsy, does there a more classic way?

working with angular 4 / Observables / typescript

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Progress indicator I am using in my angular version 4: [nprogress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/)
exact version: "ngx-progressbar": "^2.0.4".  [github source](https://github.com/murhafsousli/ngx-progressbar.git)
How to integrate?
***1)*** IN **app.component.html**
The section where header is placed:

```
<ng-progress [positionUsing]="'marginLeft'" [minimum]="0.15" [maximum]="1"
             [speed]="200" [showSpinner]="true" [direction]="'leftToRightIncreased'"
             [color]="'#5be7cb'" [trickleSpeed]="250" [thick]="true" [ease]="'linear'"
></ng-progress>
```

***2)*** In the component you want to show indicator:
`import { NgProgressService } from 'ngx-progressbar';`
`constructor(private progressService: NgProgressService)`

***3)*** where the async action starts (usually an http call):
`this.progressService.start();`
where the async action ends:
`this.progressService.done();`

Or , if you want to **bind a button state** to a `boolean` which tells to the **button** when the async action is ended and **button** automatically changes state to `disabled or enabled`, it is necessary to create a public boolean field:
`public isActionExecuting: boolean;` 
set this property to `true` at the beginning of the async call, and inside subscription:

```
this._myApService.getAnimalInfo(animal.id).subscribe((animalInfo: AnimalInfo) => { 
    //some stuff
    this.isActionExecuting = false;
    //other stuff
    //if other async stuff starts here, then inside the subscription of that async should mark with false

})
```

Having that, from **HTML** you can bind the button disable attribute:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-action"
              [disabled]="isActionExecuting"
              (click)="startAsyncAction()">Start Async Action</button>
```